# Create a Json file from the java code

Tags: java, json

How to create the following JSON file using java code ?

```
{
"mode":"EXTENDED",
"vertices": [
    {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "loppper"
        },
        "lang": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "java"
        },
        "_id": "3",
        "_type": "vertex"
    },
    {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "vadas"
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "value": 27
        },
        "_id": "2",
        "_type": "vertex"
    },
    {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "marko"
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "value": 29
        },
        "_id": "1",
        "_type": "vertex"
    },
     {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "mark12"
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "value": 31
        },
        "_id": "31",
        "_type": "vertex"
    },


    {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "peter"
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer",
            "value": 35
        },
        "_id": "6",
        "_type": "vertex"
    }]}
```

Confused between JSONObject and JSONArray. Can anyone please help. 
I am able to create

```
{
"mode":"Extended",
"vertices" : [
[(1)
](2)
]
}
```

but i need curly brackets instead of square brackets in (1) (2)

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use the [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to generate JSON strings (and to parse them). It is as simple as creating a set of objects, holding the data. Afterwards, you call [`Gson.toJson(obj)`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have written some util class for me to generate JSON by converting Map and List object

```
public static String parseMapToJSONString(Map<String,Object> mapData){
    StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder("{");
    int iteration = 0;
    for(String key: mapData.keySet()){
        if( mapData.get(key) instanceof List){
            jsonData.append("\"").append(key).append("\"").append(":")
                    .append(parseListToJSONString((List<Object>) mapData.get(key)));
        } else if(mapData.get(key) instanceof Map){
            jsonData.append("\"").append(key).append("\"").append(":")
                    .append(parseMapToJSONString((Map<String,Object>) mapData.get(key)));
        } else {
            jsonData.append("\"").append(key).append("\"").append(":").append("\"").append(mapData.get(key).toString()).append("\"");
        }
        if(mapData.size() > 1 && iteration < mapData.size() - 1){
            jsonData.append(",");
        }
        iteration++;
    }
    jsonData.append("}");
    return jsonData.toString();
}

public static String parseListToJSONString(List<Object> listData){
    StringBuilder jsonListData = new StringBuilder("[");
    int iteration = 0;
    for(Object value: listData){
        if(value instanceof String){
            jsonListData.append("\"").append(value.toString()).append("\"");
        } else if(value instanceof Map){
            jsonListData.append(parseMapToJSONString((Map<String,Object>) value));
        }
        if(iteration < listData.size()-1){
            jsonListData.append(",");
        }
        iteration++;
    }
    jsonListData.append("]");
    return jsonListData.toString();
}
```

Some sample code

```
    Map<String,Object> testMap1 = new HashMap();
    testMap1.put("name", "Oscar");
    testMap1.put("email","peter@yahoo.com");

    List<String> majorList = new ArrayList();
    majorList.add("Math");
    majorList.add("Physics");
    testMap1.put("major",majorList);

    Map<String,Object> testMap2 = new HashMap();
    testMap2.put("name", "Alice");
    testMap2.put("school", "ABC");
    testMap1.put("mother",testMap2);

    List<Map<String,Object>> friendList = new ArrayList();
    Map<String,Object> testMap3 = new HashMap();
    testMap3.put("name", "Peter");
    testMap3.put("school", "ABC");
    Map<String,Object> testMap4 = new HashMap();
    testMap4.put("name", "Tom");
    testMap4.put("school", "ABC");
    friendList.add(testMap3);
    friendList.add(testMap4);

    testMap1.put("friends",friendList);
    System.out.println(JSONParserService.parseMapToJSONString(testMap1));
```